# How to set session flash message in commad symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I've a file in testBundle>Command>ReportCommand.php where I want to set flash message like below but it's not working. I've also added this namespace but it didn't work too:`-use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`

```
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'notice', sprintf('%s email sent!', str_replace('_', ' ', ucfirst($type)))
            );
```

Comment: Do run ReportCommand from command line? If yes there isn't session in this case.

Comment: Why do you want flash messages to be set? need to know the purpose of what you want to achieve to give you a proper answer because now you want to do something but we dont know for what, where do you want to show the notice?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use sessions from command line, you can only use them with the HTTP way. Try to store your message in a différent way :

- In a file
- In your MySQL database
- In a RAM cache (E.g. redis)
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use outer interface to show the message on command prompt. 

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class classname extends ContainerAwareCommand {
    protected function configure()
    {
        // command details
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // your script code
        $output->writeln("Your message");
    }
}
```